# How can Python heredoc be used as input for a Bash process substitution?

Tags: python, bash, process-substitution

I have a Python script that defines a configuration for tmux and then launches tmux with this configuration. The configuration is stored as a heredoc in Python and I want to use this in a Bash process substitution when executing the Bash launch command for tmux.

So, I'm looking to do something like this:

```
configuration = \
"""
set -g set-remain-on-exit on
new -s "FULL"
set-option -g prefix C-a
unbind C-b
bind - split-window -v
bind | split-window -h
## colours
set-option -g window-status-current-bg yellow
set-option -g pane-active-border-fg yellow
set -g status-fg black
set -g status-bg '#FEFE0A'
set -g message-fg black
set -g message-bg '#FEFE0A'
set -g message-command-fg black
set -g message-command-bg '#FEFE0A'
set-option -g mode-keys vi
set -g history-limit 5000
## mouse mode
set -g mode-mouse on
set -g mouse-select-pane on
set -g mouse-select-window on
set -g mouse-resize-pane on # resize panes with mouse (drag borders)
## status
set-option -g status-interval 1
set-option -g status-left-length 20
set-option -g status-left ''
set-option -g status-right '%Y-%m-%dT%H%M%S '
## run programs in panes
# split left-right
split-window -h
# split left up
select-pane -t 0
split-window -v
select-pane -t 0
split-window -v
select-pane -t 0
split-window -v
select-pane -t 3
split-window -v
select-pane -t 0
send-keys 'ranger' Enter
select-pane -t 1
send-keys 'clear' Enter
select-pane -t 2
#send-keys 'htop' Enter
select-pane -t 3
send-keys 'elinks http://arxiv.org/list/hep-ph/new' Enter
select-pane -t 4
send-keys 'cmus' Enter
select-pane -t 5
send-keys 'ranger' Enter
select-pane -t 4
set -g set-remain-on-exit off
"""

command = executable + " -f <(echo " + configuration + ") attach"
os.system(command)
```

What should I change to get this working?

Comment: What happens when you try this?

Comment: @cdarke Hi there. When I run this, I get the error ```sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected```.

Comment: I think the problem is with the `<( )` syntax.  `os.system()` runs `sh` not `bash`.

Comment: Do you know if `tmux` supports `-f -` to read stdin?  (I don't have tmux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python's `os.system()` is defined in terms of C's `system()` function, which runs the given command via `/bin/sh -c <the command>`.  Even if /bin/sh is an alias for bash, when bash is started *as* `sh`, it operates in POSIX mode, and POSIX does not provide process substitution (the `<(<command>)`).

It looks like your best bet is probably to write the configuration to a temporary file, and then specify that file's name in your command.  If you have the `mktemp` command available to you, then it is a good candidate for making the temp file.  Maybe something along these lines would do it:

```
command = "config=`mktemp` && { echo \"" + configuration + "\" > $config; "
        + executable + " -f $config attach; unlink $config; }"
```

Moreover, even if it were available to you, bash process substitution is a *redirection*.  It affects the standard input (or standard output) if the process being launched, and does not take the place of a file name.

Comment: I have been playing with `bash -c` and the command, and have come to the same conclusion.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your solution on that. I understand about the Bash/shell problem now. It might be nice to create a Bash environment variable to store the configuration rather than a temporary file in order to avoid unnecessary hard drive access, but I'm not quite sure how to do this without running into character escaping problems with the heredoc.

Comment: @d3pd, as far as I can tell, `tmux` requires you to provide any needed configuration *in a file*, and it will read from its default configuration file(s) if you do not specify an alternative via the `-f` option.  I don't see any way to configure it via the environment.  At least, that's how I read the docs; I don't actually use `tmux` myself.  What's the big problem with hard drive access?  Reading a config file is going to be extremely cheap compared to loading `tmux` itself.

Comment: The process substitution construct (```<()```)  in Bash allows for the use of something like an environment variable in place of a file and I have confirmed that this works fine (e.g. ```tmux -f <(echo "${configuration}") attach```). The problem with moving out of Python is either having Bash available or being able to convert the configuration in the Python heredoc to a Bash heredoc for use with tmux via process substitution.

Yes, the hard drive usage would be small, but I don't like saving to files when I can keep the details simply in a volatile variable.